# excel - separate email and url from same cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a list in Excel that looks like this:

```
Column A
skfjkdf@kasldfj.com
fjls@fdkjd.comhttp://www.kdfj.com
dfkjdf@kdlfj.eshttp://djfkdsf
dkfjs@kljf.com
kjsfld@klfjlf.cahttp://www...
```

there are cells with just the email address
and there are cells with email and url together (always without space)

I would like the single emails to stay in Column A
and the ones together separated: Email Column A, URL Column B

I've tried with TRIM, LEFT, RIGHT and SUBSTITUTE but I couldn't figure it out.

Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two ways to do this.. One without formulas and one with

- In Excel push *Ctrl+H* to bring up the Find and Replace dialog.
  Replace "http" with " http" (note the space)

  Then select the cells you want to split and go to *Data > Texts to
  Columns*. Make sure to have it delimit on the space.
- To extract just the E-mail use

  ```
  =LEFT(A1,SEARCH("http",A1,1)-1)
  ```

  To extract just the site use

  ```
  =RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("http",A1,1)+1)
  ```

  This assumes all your sites start with "http"

Now the email and URL should be split.

Comment: I like that first method you suggest, easy peasy without getting complicated.

Answer (score 1):

This is quick and dirty and I'm sure will be critiqued, I welcome it :)

```
    Sub test()

    Range("A1").Select
    Do Until ActiveCell = ""
        this = ActiveCell.Value
        iLen = Len(this)
        charnum = InStr(this, "http")
    If charnum <> 0 Then
        iLen2 = iLen - charnum + 1
        iLen3 = charnum - 1
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Mid(ActiveCell.Value, charnum, iLen2)
        ActiveCell.Value = Left(ActiveCell, iLen3)
     Else
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
     End If
    Loop
   End Sub
```